# Expected 5 arguments given 4 in socker server constructor overriding

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tcp, socketserver, constructor-overloading

I'm trying to override the constructor of the TCPHandler class so that I can pass variables to the handler function, I have come across other posts on stack but they weren't clear to me. I have to pass a byte array to the sendall function in the `handle()` method, and on looking up for different approaches to do the above, overriding the constructor was the most preferred option.

The is my code:

```
import SocketServer
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    :file:   TCP Handler
    :author: Prat, Warsaw, PL
    """
    def handle(self):

            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print "{} Sent: {}".format(self.client_address[0], self.data[0:3])

            self.request.sendall(bytearray(self.payload_))
            server.server_close()

class superTCPHandler(SocketServer.TCPServer):
        def __init__(self,request, client_address, server, payload_):
            self.payload_ = (payload_)
            SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self,request, client_address, BaseRequestHandler, payload_)


        def handle(self):
            self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
            print "{} Sent: {}".format(self.client_address[0], self.data[0:3])


            self.request.sendall(self.payload_)
            print self.payload_ 
            server.server_close()

if __name__ == "__main__": 
            print (help(superTCPHandler ))

            HOST, PORT = "192.168.4.4", 12345
            #server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
            custom_server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), superTCPHandler, bytearray([114, 100, 100 ,100, 2]))
            print "Listening on {}:{}".format(HOST, PORT)
            custom_server.handle_request()
```

When I print out the `help(superTCPHandler))`, the `handle()` function does not show its inheritance, the code compiles but does nothing, or the client receives nothing. I'm assuming that the `handle()` function isn't being called from my custom class. I do have a strong feeling that the mistake is somewhere in the `__init__` part, i tried multiple times with different approaches, but didn't work out. What is the correct method to do so?

I'm not sure if I have to create an object of the basic class(MyTCPHandler) hence I have commented the server object before initializing custom_server object. I'm kinda new to socket programming, please forgive me for my blind mistakes.

This is the error I get:

> custom_server = superTCPHandler((HOST, PORT), superTCPHandler, bytearray([114, 100, 100 ,100, 2]))
>
> TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)
>   [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of issues:

- superTCPHandler is not a handler because it is derived from TCPServer.
- The signature of __init_ is wrong in superTCPHandler.
- custom_server doesn't instantiate a derived TCPServer class.

The following code derives a custom server that takes an additional payload parameter.  That parameter is added as a member variable of the server instance.  The handler retrieves the server instance's payload.

```
#!python2
import SocketServer
class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        print "{} Sent: {}".format(self.client_address[0], self.data[0:3])
        self.request.sendall(bytearray(self.server.payload_))

class superTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, payload_, bind_and_activate=True):
        self.payload_ = payload_
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    HOST,PORT = '',12345
    custom_server = superTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler, bytearray([114, 100, 100 ,100, 2]))
    print "Listening on {}:{}".format(HOST, PORT)
    custom_server.handle_request()
```